# Intel XDK build for Android not working

Tags: intel-xdk

I am very new to Intel XDK.

To build my initial concepts, I made a very simple html 5 hello world page and it is working fine when running under EMULATE tab.

I build the app for Android, email to my address, download on mobile and installed it as well.

But after installation, when I start the application, it shows the first page with title "Html5 App Development" and then a blank White screen, that's it, I am not able to view my index.html page on the mobile.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post link to the apk file

Comment: Here it is: https://am-xdk2.s3.amazonaws.com/cust.78a457ce-8817-4455-be8e-191a3a345cdf/app.14c4dd9c-28cf-49c9-8c7d-85eed3e2b6b6/ANDROID/MobileWebApp.Android.4.2.20140122030526.apk

Comment: cannot access it, put on dropbox

Comment: Show your index.html file code.

Comment: Me, too, having same problem.

Comment: shree, in my case I was missing index file.

Comment: @TariqYousuf Any idea, how to solve this? I do have Index.html file.

Comment: Akash, I had this problem beacuase I initially created the app outside xdk and then tried build it for android. Simple approach could be to start within XDK with a simple one page application, build it for say android(it will work for sure), then add pages to it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that by now you have solved the problem but in case other people run into this thread. We had the same issue at times with our app until we tracked down the problem to the way the init and document ready gets fired.
Tweaking with the document ready features did the trick for us.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably have it drawn at some point offscreen, due to the pixels rendered in the display vs actual pixels.

Try setting the viewport/screen size to handle this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/viewport-pixels-trouble-intel-xdk